# Long tail physical product marketing: is Wordpress suitable?

Tags: seo, wordpress, marketing, jekyll, products

A small-medium size company selling to business, government and wholesalers manufactures 10,000 products.

Company has a skilled graphic designer and a couple of programmers (including php) but none of them have much website experience and are not available to work full time on the website.

Company sell under their own name in their home country and as an OEM overseas - mostly to the EU. They now wish to also market under their own name overseas (but do not need ecommerce).

Existing company website is in the local language and English. Product updates and news only mean changes perhaps once a month but the existing asp website is difficult to maintain and for some reason I don't understand the downloadable product catalogs don't seem to be being indexed by Google, although they are pdfs and the text is selectable.

The graphic designer (who is also the director of marketing) would like a completely new website. Obviously the best selling product lines can continue to have their own custom designed pages but how best to deal with the long tail? The company product database has product number, name and perhaps a few words of description in English and the local language and small picture for each product and I can easily run an extract and/or copy part of the database to be used by a website. I would like when someone searches for the product name of one of these obscure gizmos for the company to appear in search results.

My initial thought would be to use Jeykyll (which I have no experience of) to generate a static site with a page for each group of products and then have the graphic designer customize the most popular groups.

However the graphic designer is wondering whether Wordpress would be suitable. I have a little Wordpress experience and if you have any ideas which would be reasonably simple to maintain could try them out. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion and experience, the best way to deal with long tail is to tie longtail keywords on category pages. If you try to go with an own landing page for a long tail keyword you quickly risc an amount of thin content pages.

Wordpress can handle a very big amount of pages. But the main problem isn't an amount of pages, but an amount of concurrent requests. To handle them you should pay very big attention to the caching, and, specially, proactive warm caching.

The other way is, as you mentioned, to generate static pages from (maybe local WP installation) and host them in the web. This way allows you to get rid of time consuming dynamic, like database querying - you deliver just pure HTML, which is faster then fast.